# Sending data to another controller - Without going to him

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swift3, controller

I want to send data to another controller without opening it.
[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PeiEO.png)

Main controller:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
   let vc = SecondViewController()
   vc.test = "ABCDFER"
}
```

Second controller:

```
var test: String

override func viewDidLoad() {
   print(test)
}
```

How to do it?

Comment: Create the object of the view controller and set its properties.

Comment: I tried to do it but unfortunately it does not work

Comment: _"I tried to do it but unfortunately it does not work"_ - please post this code, and we may be able to help.

Comment: I added the code

Comment: Do you ever present the view controller that you create with `let vc = SecondViewController()`?

Comment: Yes, I call it later

Comment: If you mean in some other function, then you *can't* call it later.  The scope of `vc` is the main controller's `viewDidLoad` method.  Or, is there more to `viewDidLoad` that you're not showing?

Comment: some other method?

Comment: static var test: String   instead of var test: String. So you can set data by SecondViewController.test = "ABCDFER"

Answer (score 1):

It works for me this way

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {


    var otherViewController: OtherViewController!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        otherViewController = OtherViewController()
        otherViewController.test = "ABCDFER"
    }

    @IBAction func press() {
        self.show(self.otherViewController, sender: nil)
    }

}

class OtherViewController: UIViewController {


    var test: String!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        print(test)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your `Main` controller, as soon as `viewDidLoad()` finishes your instance of `SecondViewController` is destroyed / deallocated. If you want to set a value in`SecondViewController` at that point, so you can "use" it later, you need to keep a reference to that instance:

So, in Main controller:

```
var secondVC: SecondViewController?

override func viewDidLoad() {
   secondVC = SecondViewController()
   secondVC.test = "ABCDFER"
}
```

Now, later - perhaps on a button tap - you want to use that *same* instance:

```
@IBAction func buttonTap(_ sender: Any) {
    print("test in secondVC:", secondVC?.test)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Keep in mind the view life cycle, if the view viewDidLoad() it's only executed when loading the view through a xib or when view related actions are done with the controller, like addSubview().

The value is being passed and will not be deallocated while your main controller is alive.

You can force a lifecycle event to be called, but isn't recommended at all.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    var otherViewController: OtherViewController!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        otherViewController = OtherViewController()
        otherViewController.test = "ABCDFER"
        //Do not do this
        otherViewController.viewDidLoad()
    }
```

}

```
class OtherViewController: UIViewController {
    var test: String!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        print(test)
    }
}
```